# BigQuery - BackEnd error when loading from JAVA API

Tags: java, api, google-bigquery

I'm getting 503 - Backend error when trying to set up a load job using JAVA API.

The file I am trying to load is on Google Cloud Storage, and if I try to load the data from BigQuery web interface, telling that I want to load from Google Cloud Storage, everything 
works.

Probably there is something wrong with how I use APIs.

Here is the code:

```
            String url = "[GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_URL];

    Job job = new Job();
    JobConfiguration config = new JobConfiguration();
    JobConfigurationLoad loadConfig = new JobConfigurationLoad();

    config.setLoad(loadConfig);

    job.setConfiguration(config);

    List<String> sources = new ArrayList<String>();
    sources.add("gs://" + url);
    loadConfig.setSourceUris(sources);

    TableReference tableRef = new TableReference();
    tableRef.setDatasetId("Foo");
    tableRef.setTableId("Bar");
    tableRef.setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);
    loadConfig.setDestinationTable(tableRef);

    List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<TableFieldSchema>();
    TableFieldSchema field = new TableFieldSchema();

            ..... A LOT OF FIELDS

            field.setName("real_dollars_balance");
    field.setType("float");

    fields.add(field);
            TableSchema schema = new TableSchema();
    schema.setFields(fields);
    loadConfig.setSchema(schema);

    Insert insert = bigquery.jobs().insert(PROJECT_ID, job);
    insert.setProjectId(PROJECT_ID);
    JobReference jobId = insert.execute().getJobReference();
```

I can't get a valid Job reference as the insert operation fails, I don't see any new job on BigQuery.
I'm correctly authenticated on BigQuery, I can browse data sets and tables.
Do I miss something?

EDIT - The "execute()" method call throws an exeption, GoogleJsonResponseException, containing this:

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service           Unavailable
 {
   "code" : 503,
   "errors" : [ {
      "domain" : "global",
      "message" : "Backend Error",
      "reason" : "backendError"
    } ],
   "message" : "Backend Error"
  }
```

And, well, it never becomes "available".
I really don't know what I am missing. 
How you people set automatic procedure to load data on Google BigQuery? The docs on Google is not clear like I expected for a service like this.

Comment: Are you consistently getting this 503 error?

Comment: I get 503 also if, for example, pass a "sources" object ... empty! So probably there is something else missing.

Comment: Can you include a job id of a failed job?

Comment: The problem is, I have no job id, the "execute" method throws   exception, a GoogleResponseJsonException. I edited the question to better clarify my problem.

Comment: You code seems totally legit, I use almost the same in my case. What I would recommend to investigate is first to try to also set the "writeDisposition" property, which I set in my code. It's supposed to be optional but you never know.


If that does not change anything, try with a more simple schema, only one columns. Maybe BQ is having a hard time parsing your schema.