# Frequent 503 errors raised from BigQuery Streaming API

Tags: google-bigquery

**Streaming data into BigQuery keeps failing due to the following error, which occurs more frequently recently:**

```
com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException: 503 Service Unavailable
{
  "code" : 503,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "message" : "Connection error. Please try again.",
    "reason" : "backendError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Connection error. Please try again."
}
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.json.GoogleJsonResponseException.from(GoogleJsonResponseException.java:145)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:113)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.json.AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.newExceptionOnError(AbstractGoogleJsonClientRequest.java:40)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest$1.interceptResponse(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:312)
        at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:1049)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:410)
        at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:343)
```

**Relevant question references:**

- [Getting high rate of 503 errors with BigQuery Streaming API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22073543/getting-high-rate-of-503-errors-with-bigquery-streaming-api)
- [BigQuery - BackEnd error when loading from JAVA API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815073/bigquery-backend-error-when-loading-from-java-api)

Comment: @JordanTigani can you check these 3?

Comment: can you provide your project ID?

Comment: Hi Jordan. Our project id is gdfp-7414. We got the same error again today for our load - "503: Connection error. Please try again.". This is now happening daily. It was fine last week.

Answer (score 2):

We (the BigQuery team) are looking into your report of increased connection errors. From the internal monitoring, there hasn't been global a spike in connection errors in the last several days. However, that doesn't mean that your tables, specifically, weren't affected.

Connection errors can be tricky to chase down, because they can be caused by errors before they get to the BigQuery servers or after they leave. The more information your can provide, the easier it is for us to diagnose the issue.

The best practice for streaming input is to handle temporary errors like this to retry the request. It can be a little tricky, since when you get a connection error you don't actually know  whether the insert succeeded. If you include a unique `insertId` with your data (see the documentation [here](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tabledata/insertAll)), you can safely resend the request (within the deduplication window period, which I think is 15 minutes) without worrying that the same row will get added multiple times.

Comment: Thanks Jordan. Completely understand that these types of errors are hard to track down. But until we build in the error handling for the 503's (which may take a few days to implement and deploy to our application servers) is there any other information I can give you to try and help you find/resolve this problem? The issue is that we have a daily load for BigQuery which feeds a reporting solution for our business and we haven't been able to successfully update BigQuery since Sunday 16th.