# Streaming insert API throws 500 errors while using with google-api-java-clients batch request

Tags: google-bigquery

We are using streaming insert API along with google-api-java-clients batch request.

Initially everything was fine but after some time it started throwing so many 500 errors:

```
{"code":500,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Unexpected. Please try again.","reason":"internalError"}],"message":"Unexpected. Please try again."}
```

Code snippet is below:

```
val batch = client.batch()   
val request = new TableDataInsertAllRequest()
request.setRows(rows)
val insertAll = client.tabledata().insertAll(ProjectId, datasetId, tableId, request)
insertAll.queue(batch, new MyCallback(datasetId, tableId, rows, retryAttempt))
```

Sometimes we are getting **BackEndError** as well

```
{"code":500,"errors":[{"domain":"global","message":"Backend Error","reason":"backendError"}],"message":"Backend Error"}
```

**NOTE:** Prior to getting errors we got below error:

```
java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:150) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:121) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(InputRecord.java:312) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(InputRecord.java:350) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:927) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:884) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(AppInputStream.java:102) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:633) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:579) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1322) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at java.net.HttpURLConnection.getResponseCode(HttpURLConnection.java:468) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getResponseCode(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:338) ~[na:1.7.0_06]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpResponse.<init>(NetHttpResponse.java:36) ~[google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar:1.18.0-rc]
    at com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpRequest.execute(NetHttpRequest.java:94) ~[google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar:1.18.0-rc]
    at com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.execute(HttpRequest.java:965) ~[google-http-client-1.18.0-rc.jar:1.18.0-rc]
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.batch.BatchRequest.execute(BatchRequest.java:241) ~[google-api-client-1.18.0-rc.jar:1.18.0-rc]
```

**Questions**

- What is the cause of this?
- What should we do to fix this?

**EDIT**
 - Project id is  ***deft-virtue-628***
 - We are executing using streaming insert api and do not have job id.

Comment: do you have a list of jobs id? and mention the project id as well, the BQ team will be able to identify individual problems with those mentioned here.

Answer (score 0):

We were kind of experienced same issues before. Here are some of our findings, hope them can help you a bit.

1. regarding to java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Read timed out: it by a big chance wasn't due to the Bigquery side, but could be your system resource (JVM or network socket or relative things) get exhausted. We originally ran our program on a virtual machine on Windows Server 2008R2 when we experienced so many socket timed out. Since we moved to a new server and ran our program on native machine, we have barely seen this exceptions. Also, this time out would sometimes cause other exceptions such as SSL connection closed during handshake and etc.
2. as of Bigquery 500's error: we were not be able to find a way to avoid it, since it didn't show any pattern, Bigquery doesn't totally forbid or fail your following requests.  Simply do backoff won't help to avoid this error, especially if you are using multithread, it's hard to control backoff time accurately. So, what we did was put data back to queue if 500 error happened and retry, the fact was that averagely after 1-2 times of retry, it success. Although we are still waiting for advises on an optimized way to deal with this error, we kind of just keep retrying as for now. By doing this, 500's error happens, but we can still get all of our data streamed into Bigquery.

Comment: I found [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22468181/frequent-503-errors-raised-from-bigquery-streaming-api?rq=1) also suggested retry at 500's error with insertId.

Comment: We implemented the retry mechanism already. But because of so many errors, the retry path is causing issues with normal execution.
We just wanted to know what could be the reason behind these? Is it due to our usage of api or something from BQ side? Also how can we mitigate these issues?

Comment: Well, if you check out the link I gave you and other posts around 500's, you might get an idea that it's not a issue can be located within a short time. As of our experience, you may need to design a better mechanism to handle such many and frequent 500's error so that it won't cause issues with normal execution.  What kind of issues it now cause to normal execution?